# least wear n tear drive from Colorado Springs to Salt Lake City in August?

Tags: driving, routes

I have to make an emergent drive in a 1999 Pontiac Grand Prix. looking for advice on the best route should I have car issues> car is a little driven with average mileage for age. new tires and routine maintenance. I hope to make it there and back and so which route should I use to ensure the round trip of course outside any unforeseen issues, car wrex etc?

Comment: Don't forget that I-70 is currently closed through Glenwood Canyon!

Comment: According to [Rome2Rio](https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Colorado-Springs/Salt-Lake-City) if you take a bus (or drive) to Denver then fly, it will cost about the same as driving all the way (but with no wear/tear). It should be a lot quicker too.

Comment: @NateEldredge I-25 north to Fort Collins, then NW on US287 to Laramie WY, and then I-80 west to SLC is a few miles further than taking I-70, but almost a whole hour shorter...even if I-70 were open.

Answer (score 3):

With Interstate 70 closed through Glenwood Canyon due to mudslides, there's really only one option: take Interstate 25 north to Interstate 80, then take I-80 west to Salt Lake City.

Google offers the option of cutting the I-25/I-80 corner via US-287.  That saves about 20 miles, but US-287 is typically one lane each way with narrow shoulders, while the interstates are two lanes each way with wide shoulders.  If your car does develop a problem, the interstates offer a better option for pulling off to the side (and a tow truck is likely to get to you faster).

Answer (score 1):

If you drive, you'll buy about $200 in fuel, the trip will take two to four days of your time, and there will be some wear on the car.

I'll go one further than @NateEldredge: consider flying direct from Colorado Springs to SLC and return. Delta flies several non-stops each day on this route. Flying will cost about $100 more out-of-pocket than driving, but it will save two to four days of your time, remove car-related risks, and there will be no wear on the car.

If you can do your business in SLC without a car (or can rent or borrow one for a day or two), this may make better sense than driving the whole way.

Comment: Colorado Springs to SLC is at most 600 miles.  You'd have to be driving really really slow to take 4 days to do that as a return trip

Comment: @PeterM You and me, sure. But the OP comes across as someone who's not at ease driving. I can certainly see a timorous driver taking a day or two each way. All in all, I don't think they'd react as we do.

Comment: If they are driving on Freeway driving then they are likely to be subjected to minimum speed limits.  So that potentially forces the issue.

Comment: Google puts it at about 9 hours of driving each way without stops or abnormal traffic. Add in some stops, maybe an unexpected traffic jam, and it's quite reasonable to think of it as a 1-2 day drive in each direction depending on your comfort level with long drives, so 2-4 days for a round trip sounds about right.